# In C#,two different methods to convert a gif file to byte[]

Tags: c#, image, stream, byte, gif

I want to convert a gif file to byte[].

I tried two method, but the result is different.Which one is right?

Method 1:

> Using the `bytes =File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)`; This return a byte array.

Methond 2:

> ```
>  private byte[] ImageToBytes(Image image, ImageFormat format)
>         {
>             using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
>             {
>                 image.Save(ms, format);
>                 return ms.ToArray();
>             }
>         }
>
> Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"c:\\1.gif");
> ```
>
> Then call
>   `bytes = ImageToBytes(image, ImageFormat.Gif);`

The two bytes have a little bit of difference. Which one I should trust?

Answer (score 1):

Your "methond 2" is reencoding/recompressing the file. It's likely to be significantly different, and (in all likelihood) degraded in quality.

Comment: If the `ImageFormat.Gif` were changed to `ImageFormat.Bmp` or `ImageFormat.Png` though, wouldn't that make them functionally equivalent?

Comment: No. Copying the bytes from disk is fundamentally different to making an in memory conversion between different image formats. The source is gif. Of course `ImageFormat.Bmp` or `ImageFormat.Png` will be different.

Comment: Right, of course, I was just thinking about the pixel data, not the rest of the file.  Since Bmp and Png are generally lossless formats, there shouldn't be a degradation in image quality if the conversion is made, though the header and such will be quite different, right?

Comment: Gif is also a lossless format.  The pixels don't change when repeatedly re-encode.  Something like metadata or animation frames could be a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Both are "right", in that they're the result of what you told the computer to do.  One is the byte array directly from the file, and the other is the result of decoding the file and re-encoding it, which could end up being the exact same array, or wildly different.  Likely the one you want is the first one, since it's significantly faster since it doesn't go through the decode/encode process and keeps the original data.  The only reason I can think of to use the second one is if you really need to analyze the output of the .NET gif encoding process for some reason.

The second option is the same as the below, except without needing the temp file because it does everything in memory.  So all you're doing is loading it then saving it then loading it again.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"c:\1.gif"); 
image.Save("c:\1_temp.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);
bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\1_temp.gif");
```